# How can a do a "greatest-n-per-group" query in django?

Tags: sql, django, join, greatest-n-per-group

(This is the django version of the thread at [SQL join: selecting the last records in a one-to-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111384/))

Suppose I have a table of customers and a table of purchases. Each purchase belongs to one customer. I want to get a list of all customers along with their last purchase. Can it be done without raw SQL and without multiple database queries?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django Query That Get Most Recent Objects From Different Categories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074514/django-query-that-get-most-recent-objects-from-different-categories)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at similar discussion:

[Django Query That Get Most Recent Objects From Different Categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074514/django-query-that-get-most-recent-objects-from-different-categories/2076665#2076665)

Comment: In fact, this is a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this in one query in Django. You can get the customer with just the **date** of their most recent purchase like this:

```
from django.db.models import Max
customers = Customer.objects.annotate(Max('purchase__date'))
```

but you don't automatically get access to the actual purchase this way.

Comment: In Django 2 and 3, this restriction has been lifted. See the link in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    customers с
LEFT JOIN
        purchases p
ON      p.id = 
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    purchases pl
        WHERE   pl.customer = c.id
        ORDER BY
                pl.customer DESC, pl.date DESC
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

Make sure you have a composite index on `purchases (customer, date)` if your table is `InnoDB`, or on `purchases (customer, date, id)` if your table is `MyISAM`.

Comment: Why don't we need id in the index for InnoDB?

Comment: `@netvope`: because `InnoDB` is index organized and implicitly contains the `PRIMARY KEY` as a row pointer in every index.