# Django QuerySet aggregate and join

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm quite new to Django, I'm trying to figure out how to solve this problem.
This is my model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class ProductDetail(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=Decimal('999.99'))
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    validity_tms = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Basically, for each Product I want to track price and availability changes. For this reason, many ProductDetail exist for each Product.

When needed, I need to get *code*, *name*, *available* and *price* fields for every product, but only related to the ProductDetail with the maximum validity_tms for each product.

This QuerySet contains only a part of the informations I need:

```
ProductDetail.objects.values('product').annotate(max_date=Max('validity_tms'))
```

How can I retrieve *price* and *available* fields, too?

Is there a way to solve this? Did I make something wrong in the model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> @Todor I need the one with the greatest `validity_tms`

Then you are basically looking for a [greatest-1-per-group](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/greatest-n-per-group/info) query.

but <s>this is not within the [capabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111590/how-can-a-do-a-greatest-n-per-group-query-in-django) of the ORM to be done with a single query.</s>

**UPDATE**

This question make me do some digging and I just figured out that we can actually build such a query with the new staff coming from `Django 1.11`. We do this by using [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) and [OuterRef](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.OuterRef), here is how.

```
latest_product_details = ProductDetail.objects.filter(
    validity_tms=Subquery(
        (ProductDetail.objects
            .filter(product=OuterRef('product'))
            .values('product')
            .annotate(max_date=Max('validity_tms'))
            .values('max_date')[:1]
        )
    )
)

#now you can choose to work with ProductDetail itself:
for product_detail in latest_product_details.select_related('product'):
    product = product_detail.product
    print (product, product_detail)


#or you can work with Product objects and prefetch those latest details
products = Product.objects.my_complex_filtering().prefetch_related(
    models.Prefetch('productdetail_set',
        queryset=latest_product_details,
        to_attr='latest_details'
    )
)
for product in products:
    #get the first element in the list or None if Empty
    last_detail = next(iter(product.latest_details), None)
    print (product, last_detail)
```

**END OF UPDATE.**

Old answer remains for versions prior `Django 1.11`

I will offer you an alternative approach with 2 queries. This approach is not suitable in situations with many objects per group **without** any opportunities to filter down the group to only several elements. This is because, all objects all are gonna be loader into the memory, when you are gonna need only 1 per group.

```
products = (Product.objects
    .annotate(max_date=Max('productdetail__validity_tms'))
    .prefetch_related(models.Prefetch('productdetail_set',
        #this will fetch all related ProductDetails for a product
        #if one product has many of them, consider further limiting
        #the queryset with some additional filter
        #e.g. only details from the last year or something like that.
        #the idea is to lower the memory footprint, since you need only the first one
        queryset=ProductDetail.objects.order_by('-validity_tms'),
        to_attr='details'
    ))
)

#usage
for product in products:
    print({
        'product': product.id,
        'max_date': product.max_date,
        'detail_price': product.details[0].price if product.details else None,
        'detail_available': product.details[0].available if product.details else None,
    })
```

Comment: @sergionsk8 I've just updated the answer, check it out.

Answer (score -2):

Give this a try:

```
ProductDetail.objects.values('product', 'price', 'available') \
                     .annotate(max_date=Max('validity_tms'))
```

Comment: That's not correct, because in this case the query is made grouping by _product_, _price_ and _available_, leading to many results for each product. I need it to be grouped only by _product_ field.

Comment: this mean that 1 product has many prices and availabilities, which one exactly do you need?

Comment: @Todor I need the one with the greatest validity_tms