# Django aggregation query on related one-to-many objects

Tags: python, django, orm, django-orm, django-aggregation

Here is my simplified model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    pass

class TrackingPoint(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    created = models.DateField()
    data = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('item', 'created')
```

In many parts of my application I need to retrieve a set of `Item`'s and annotate each item with `data` field from latest `TrackingPoint` from each item ordered by `created` field. For example, instance `i1` of class `Item` has 3 `TrackingPoint`'s:

```
tp1 = TrackingPoint(item=i1, created=date(2010,5,15), data=23)
tp2 = TrackingPoint(item=i1, created=date(2010,5,14), data=21)
tp3 = TrackingPoint(item=i1, created=date(2010,5,12), data=120)
```

I need a query to retrieve `i1` instance annotated with `tp1.data` field value as `tp1` is the latest tracking point ordered by `created` field. That query should also return `Item`'s that don't have any `TrackingPoint`'s at all. If possible I prefer not to use `QuerySet`'s `extra` method to do this.

That's what I tried so far... and failed :(

```
Item.objects.annotate(max_created=Max('trackingpoint__created'),
                      data=Avg('trackingpoint__data')).filter(trackingpoint__created=F('max_created'))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

Here's a single query that will provide (TrackingPoint, Item)-pairs:

```
TrackingPoint.objects.annotate(max=Max('item__trackingpoint__created')).filter(max=F('created')).select_related('item').order_by('created')
```

You would have to query for items without TrackingPoints separately.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't directly answer to your question, but in case don't need exactly what you described you might be interested in greatest-n-per-group solution. You can take a look on my answer on similar question:

[Django Query That Get Most Recent Objects From Different Categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074514/django-query-that-get-most-recent-objects-from-different-categories/2076665#2076665)

-- this should apply directly to your case:

```
 items = Item.objects.annotate(tracking_point_created=Max('trackingpoint__created')) 
 trackingpoints = TrackingPoint.objects.filter(created__in=[b.tracking_point_created for b in items])
```

Note that second line can produce ambiguous results if `created` dates repeat in TrackingPoint model.

Comment: Your solution iterates through all `items`, I can't afford that.
`created` is unique within one item, I've updated my question.