# How can I write a Django query to aggregate the most recently published entry for each author of a collective blog?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Assume the following simplified models:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Author(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey('Blog', related_name='authors')

class Entry(models.Model):
   author = models.ForeignKey('Author', related_name='entries')
   published_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Given a particular blog's primary key, how would I retrieve a queryset of entries such that the queryset contains only the single most recent entry of each author?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here:

[Django query that get most recent objects from different categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074514/django-query-that-get-most-recent-objects-from-different-categories)

```
authors = Author.objects.annotate(latest_entry_published_on=Max('entries__published_on')) 
entries = Entry.objects.filter(published_on__in=[a.latest_entry_published_on for a in authors])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like:

```
Entry.objects.order_by('-published_on').values_list('author_id').distinct()
```