# one to many latest query in a filter/exclude

Tags: django, django-models, greatest-n-per-group

If I have:

```
class Info(Model):
    ...

class Ad(Model):
    listed_date = DatetimeField()
    info = ForeignKey('Info', related_name='ads', null=True)
    ....
```

I want to query `Info` based on fields within `Ad`, but only the latest ad. I know I can do:

```
Ad.objects.latest('listed_date')
```

But since I will be building up the query by chaining several filter/excludes together, I want something like:

```
query = query.filter(
    Q(**{
        'ads__latest__'+attr_name: query_value
    })
)
```

Or perhaps even have a field 'latest_ad' which always points to the most recent based on a certain field. The goal is to be able to query just the latest in the related field in a built up filter/exclude method.

How can I do this?

**EDIT**:

A little background...
I have 2 models (LegalAd, TrusteeInfo) that store scraped data about the same auction item, some of the field need a fair deal of processing to extract the necessary values (hence my decision to store the information in separate models) store the data at different stages of processing. I then attempt to combine both models into one (AuctionItem), and use properties extensively to prioritze data from TrusteeInfo over LegalAd for the similar fields they share. The problem is that I would like to query those fields, which the use of properties prohibits. So I created a manager and overrode the filter and exclude methods to hold the prioritization logic. Below is the code:

```
class LegalAd(models.Model):
    listed_date = models.DateField(null=True)  # field I would like to use for latest query
    auction = models.ForeignKey('auction_table.Auction', related_name='legal_ads', null=True)
    ...


class TrusteeInfo(models.Model):
    auction = models.OneToOneField('auction_table.Auction', null=True)
    ...


class AuctionManager(models.Manager):
    def do_query_action(self, action, kwargs):
        trusteeinfo = apps.get_model('scrapers', 'TrusteeInfo')
        trustee_fields = [field.name for field in trusteeinfo._meta.get_fields()]
        legalad = apps.get_model('scrapers', 'LegalAd')
        legalad_fields = [field.name for field in legalad._meta.get_fields()]
        related_fields = trustee_fields + legalad_fields
        auction_native_fields = [
            'legal_ads',
            'trusteeinfo',
            'properties',
            'id',
            'pk',
            'created_date',
            'updated_date'
        ]
        query = super(AuctionManager, self)
        for attr, value in kwargs.items():
            attr_base = attr.split('__')[0]  # get the base attr name
            if attr_base in auction_native_fields:
                query = getattr(query, action)(**{attr: value})
            elif attr_base in related_fields:
                qs = []
                if attr_base in trustee_fields:
                    trustee_attr_name = 'trusteeinfo__' + attr
                    qs.append(Q(**{trustee_attr_name: value}))
                if attr_base in legalad_fields:
                    legalad_attr_name = 'legalads__' + attr
                    qs.append(Q(**{legalad_attr_name: value}))
                query = getattr(query, action)(reduce(or_, qs))
            else:
                raise AttributeError("type object `Auction` has no attribute '{attr}'".format(attr=attr))
        return query.distinct()

    def filter(self, **kwargs):
        return self.do_query_action('filter', kwargs)

    def exclude(self, **kwargs):
        return self.do_query_action('exclude', kwargs)


class Auction(models.Model):
    objects = AuctionManager()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    @property
    def latest_ad(self):
        return self.legal_ads.exists() and self.legal_ads.latest('listed_date')

    @property
    def sale_datetime(self):
        if self.trusteeinfo and self.trusteeinfo.sale_datetime:
            return self.trusteeinfo.sale_datetime
        else:
            return self.latest_ad and self.latest_ad.sale_datetime

    @property
    def county(self):
        if self.trusteeinfo and self.trusteeinfo.county:
            return self.trusteeinfo.county
        else:
            return self.latest_ad and self.latest_ad.county

    @property
    def sale_location(self):
        return self.latest_ad and self.latest_ad.sale_address

    @property
    def property_addresses(self):
        if self.trusteeinfo and self.trusteeinfo.parsed_addresses.exists():
            return self.trusteeinfo.parsed_addresses
        else:
            return self.latest_ad and self.latest_ad.parsed_addresses

    @property
    def raw_addresses(self):
        if self.trusteeinfo and self.trusteeinfo.addresses:
            return self.trusteeinfo.addresses
        else:
            return self.latest_ad and self.latest_ad.addresses.get('addresses', None)

    @property
    def parcel_numbers(self):
        return self.latest_ad and self.latest_ad.parcel_numbers

    @property
    def trustee(self):
        if self.trusteeinfo:
            return self.trusteeinfo.trustee
        else:
            return self.latest_ad and self.latest_ad.trustee.get('trustee', None)

    @property
    def opening_bid(self):
        if self.trusteeinfo and self.trusteeinfo.opening_bid:
            return self.trusteeinfo.opening_bid
        else:
            return self.latest_ad and self.latest_ad.dollar_amounts.get('bid_owed', [[None]])[0][0]

    @property
    def deposit_amount(self):
        if self.trusteeinfo and self.trusteeinfo.deposit_amount:
            return self.trusteeinfo.deposit_amount
        else:
            return self.latest_ad and self.latest_ad.dollar_amounts.get('deposit', [[None]])[0][0]

    @property
    def sale_status(self):
        return self.trusteeinfo and self.trusteeinfo.sale_status

    @property
    def trustors(self):
        if self.trusteeinfo and self.trusteeinfo.parsed_names.exists():
            return self.trusteeinfo.parsed_names
        else:
            return self.latest_ad and self.latest_ad.parsed_names
```

It gets a bit more complicated with the fact that the ads are usually listed 2 at a time so there is a good chance of 2 ads showing up for the latest date, meaning I would have to run something like a `first()` method on it too. I could look out for certain kwargs and run a special query for that but how would I incorporate that into the the rest of the kwargs in the chained query? Ideally, if I could keep the one to many `legal_ads`, but also be able to do something like:

```
query.filter(latest_ad__<queryfield>=value)
```

or:

```
query.filter(legal_ads__latest__<queryfield>=value)
```

That would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is the so called [greatest-n-per-group](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/greatest-n-per-group/info) problem, its hard to deal with or even impossible with the ORM.

One way to approach the problem can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074514/django-query-that-get-most-recent-objects-from-different-categories/2076665#2076665).

In your case it could be something like this:

```
Info.objects.filter(
    ad__listed_date__in=Info.objects.annotate(
            last_date=Max('ad__listed_date')
        ).values_list('last_date', flat=True)
    #now you can add more
    #ad__<somefiled> statements
    #but you need to make it in a single `.filter` call
    #otherwise the ORM will do separate joins per `.filter` call
)
```

I personally don't like this. It's looks like a hack to me, its not very efficient and it can very easy return bad results if a penultimate `ad` in some group have an equal `listed_date` to a last `ad` in another group.

#### Workarounds

If you give us some more background about why do you need to filter on the latest_ad per info, maybe we could find another way to get the same/similar results.

However, one workaround which I prefer, is to filter on some `date_range`. For example, don't search for the `latest_ad`, but `.filter` on the `latest_ads` in `last_day` or `two` or a `week`, depending on your needs. Its pretty easy and efficient *(easy to optimize)* query.

```
Info.objects.filter(
    ad__listed_date__gte=(today-timedelta(days=1))
    #now again you can keep adding more `ad__<somefiled>` statements
    #but make sure to enclose them in a single `.filter` call.
)
```

You also mention a good workaround, if you can easy keep up-to-date `Info.latest_ad` field, then I guess you will be good to go.

If you go for that approach make sure to set `on_delete=models.SET_NULL` because the default behavior (cascade delete) can bring you problems.

```
class Info(Model):
    #...
    
    #related_name='+' prevents creating a reverse relation
    #on_delete=models.SET_NULL prevents deleting the Info object when its latest ad got deleted.
    latest_ad = models.ForeignKey('Ad', 
        related_name='+',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
```

Comment: @Verbal_Kint I vote for the approach of adding `Info.latest_ad` field and keep it up to date. I think its the best fit in your situation.

Comment: I think that's the route I'm going to take. However, would it be best to make it a one-to-one field? I was thinking about adding a method to the model that would be run every time I add new ads that would set the one-to-one with the latest ad. Although if there were a way to have that run automatically anytime new ads are added to the legal_ads one-to-many relationship that would be ideal...

Comment: Are there drawbacks to have two relationships between the 2 models (one-to-many and one-to-one)?

Comment: No there are no problem to have two relationships. About the One-to-One field, i think FK would be better, because you are restricting an ad to be last for only one info, maybe there could be a situation where the same ad will be last for two info models? About the function that can populate the last ad, you can check the django [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/signals/) framework, where you can listen for a new add event and calculate the latest. But It also depends on how you add ads, if you use bulk_create, then no signals will be fired and you need to do it manually.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the reasoning behind using `ForeignKey` instead of `OneToOneField` for the field `latest_ad`. I thought the point was to isolate 1 object so I can query it without the obstacle of the greatest-n-per-group problem you had mentioned earlier. Wouldn't creating a second relation which returns multiple objects just duplicate the problem? Thanks for your replies, they have been helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the example, the relationship is being set on the `Info` side and you eliminated the reverse relationship with the `related_name='+'` argument. But, out of curiosity, how would that differ from a `OneToOneField`?

Comment: `OneToOneField` is a `ForeignKey` + `unique=True`, which means `Info` object will always have only one `latest_ad`, the question is: should we allow an `ad` with `id=1` to be the `latest_ad` of `info` object with `id=1` and `info` object with `id=2` at the same time, or we should restrict that? `OneToOne` field restrict it (with `unique=True`), `ForeignKey` allows it (one `ad` can be latest to several `info` objects, but again every `info` object will have only one `lastest_ad`, its just shared across several `info` objects). Huh, did i make it more clear now? :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.latest()` along `.filter()`

```
Ad.objects.filter(your_filter=your_value).latest('listed_date')
```

or using `oder_by`

```
Ad.objects.filter(your_filter=your_value).order_by('-listed_date')[0]
```

Comment: There's no guarantee the one to many field I want to take the latest one from will be in the query. I am building it with many chained filter/exclude function in the manager by overriding the filter/exclude methods