# Django - Annotate multiple fields from a Subquery

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I'm working on a Django project on which i have a queryset of a 'A' objects ( `A.objects.all()` ), and i need to annotate multiple fields from a 'B' objects' Subquery. The problem is that the annotate method can only deal with one field type per parameter (DecimalField, CharField, etc.), so, in order to annotate multiple fields, i must use something like:

```
A.objects.all().annotate(b_id          =Subquery(B_queryset.values('id')[:1],
                         b_name        =Subquery(B_queryset.values('name')[:1],
                         b_other_field =Subquery(B_queryset.values('other_field')[:1],
                         ... )
```

Which is very inefficient, as it creates a new subquery/subselect on the final SQL for each field i want to annotate. I would like to use the same Subselect with multiple fields on it's values() params, and annotate them all on A's queryset. I'd like to use something like this:

```
b_subquery = Subquery(B_queryset.values('id', 'name', 'other_field', ...)[:1])
A.objects.all().annotate(b=b_subquery)
```

But when i try to do that (and access the first element `A.objects.all().annotate(b=b_subquery)[0]`) it raises an exception:

`{FieldError}Expression contains mixed types. You must set output_field.`

And if i set `Subquery(B_quer...[:1], output_field=ForeignKey(B, models.DO_NOTHING))`, i get a DB exception:

`{ProgrammingError}subquery must return only one column`

In a nutshell, the whole problem is that i have multiple Bs that "belongs" to a A, so i need to use Subquery to, for every A in `A.objects.all()`, pick a specific B and attach it on that A, using OuterRefs and a few filters (i only want a few fields of B), which seens a trivial problem for me.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Whether the query is inefficient or not depends on how good the DB engine is at spotting the common subexpressions and evaluating them only once. As this is a typical pattern in large SQL queries, one should hope they are pretty good at that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What I do in such situations is to use [prefetch-related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

```
a_qs = A.objects.all().prefetch_related(
    models.Prefetch('b_set',
        # NOTE: no need to filter with OuterRef (it wont work anyway)
        # Django automatically filter and matches B objects to A
        queryset=B_queryset,
        to_attr='b_records'
    )
)
```

Now `a.b_records` will be a list containing `a's` related `b` objects. Depending on how you filter your `B_queryset` this list may be limited to only 1 object.

Comment: Sorry for late response. Thank you very much. That is really what i was needing after all.

Comment: Is it possible to use within the same model?

Comment: @popcorn prefetch_related works based on FK/M2M fields, so if you have a self-referential foreign key, yes you should be able to use it within the same model.

Comment: How can you limit the prefetched b_set items?

Comment: @NebexElias you cannot set a `b_set` items limit, you can only add more filtration to the `b_queryset` which will result in less `b_set` items. Check [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43926433/2062318) for some more advanced filtration.

Comment: But what would a good option to get the top 5 **b_set** items? I tried using Subquery but limit doesn't seem to work with MySql.

Comment: you can use Prefetch() class to customize the query @NebexElias (on the phone, no link, but easily found in docs)

Comment: on a different note, this answer is correct as it solves the problem from OP but it does not provide a solution for subquery (which landed me here). For those using Subquery on non-related models, prefetch won’t help…

Comment: @FilipePina have you found a way around on non-related models? I'm stuck with the problem and havent found a solution yet

Comment: @nicofrlo you should do the prefetching (aka the "joining") manually by yourself. Run the 1st query, map the objects for a faster lookup, run the 2nd query iterate the objects and use the already created lookup to link them back to the related object from the first query.