# Query the n-th most recent entries for each unique type, for all types in Django

Tags: python, django

I have researched this issue and answers are about getting the most recent for each type, e.g. [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074514/django-query-that-get-most-recent-objects-from-different-categories/2076665#2076665).

The difference is I would like to get the `n` most recent items for each type, for *ALL* types. At the moment I get all items, then in python find the n-th most recent entries, which is very slow.

e.g.

```py
class CakeType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class CakeEntry(models.Model):
    cake_type = models.ForeignKey(CakeType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)    
    created = models.DateTimeField()
```

How would one get say the 5 most recent `CakeEntry`'s for all the distinct/unique `CakeType`'s?

I migrated DB from MySQL to PostgreSQL (a lot of work) so I can use Postgres's `DISTINCT ON`.

I tried the following after reading the docs:

```py
from django.db.models import F, Window
from django.db.models.functions import Rank

    cake_entries = (
        CakeEntry.objects.order_by(
            '-created'
        ).annotate(
            rank=Window(
                expression=Rank(),
                partition_by=[F('cake_type_id')],
                order_by=F('created').desc(),
            ),
        ).filter(rank__lt=5)
    )
```

But get `django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: Window is disallowed in the filter clause.` Without rank/partition I am not sure how one would do it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a way to do it with Window, because of conflicting goals:

In order to get around the filter problem, one would have to create a subquery. The problem is that subqueries used as expressions (annotations) should return 1 row in order to bind the specific rank to the specific outer reference, but Window needs the scope of all relevant rows. Illustrated best like so:

```py
# Pk 21 has rank 3
CakeEntry.objects.all().annotate(rank=rank).values("rank", "pk")[:3]
Out[11]: <QuerySet [{'pk': 2, 'rank': 1}, {'pk': 1, 'rank': 2}, {'pk': 21, 'rank': 3}]>
# Due to filter, pk 21 has rank 1, even though you seemingly filter after the annotation
CakeEntry.objects.all().annotate(rank=rank).values("rank", "pk").filter(pk=21)
Out[12]: <QuerySet [{'pk': 21, 'rank': 1}]>
```

The closest I could come up with is this:

```py
class CakeEntryManager(models.Manager):
    def top5_per_type(self):
        cake_types = CakeType.objects.all()
        qs = self.get_queryset()
        results = qs.none()
        for ct in cake_types:
            results = results.union(qs.filter(cake_type=ct).order_by("-created")[:5])
        return results.order_by("cake_type", "-created")
```

Comment: Thanks for giving it such a good shot. That does look like quite a reasonable way to do it. An alternate approach is to perform a windowing query to just get the ids, clean up the ids, then pass the id list into another query to get the full parameters and perform the joins. I may profile but approaches. Thanks again!