# Django: Get latest record before certain date for all given users

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

So I have table the looks something like this

| user_id | value | date_created |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 2022-8-14 |
| 2 | 11 | 2022-8-14 |
| 3 | 12 | 2022-8-14 |
| 1 | 13 | 2022-8-15 |
| 2 | 14 | 2022-8-15 |
| 3 | 15 | 2022-8-15 |
| 1 | 10 | 2022-8-16 |
| 2 | 11 | 2022-8-16 |
| 3 | 12 | 2022-8-16 |

I want to find latest record before a certain date for given users. Following query filters all records for given users before a certain date.

```py
UserData.objects.filter(user_id__in=user_list, date_created__lte=start_date)
```

How do I modify this query to get only the latest rows before the start date for each user. For example if the start date is 15 August it should give rows 4 to 6 from the table.

PS: Date created is a simplification, it should be datetime and there can be multiple values on each day by same users.

Comment: It seems like you want to look it up by exact date? Not the less than, right?

Comment: @vinkomlacic I want latest records before a certain date

Comment: You can use slice operator to limit the query to a number of records. For example, limit to 10 latest records: `UserData.objects.filter(user_id__in=user_list, date_created__lte=start_date)[:10]`. Django querysets are lazy so this won't query all records and then slice it - it will only query 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database backend is PostgreSQL, Django supports specifying fields in `.distinct`

```
UserData.objects.filter(user_id__in=user_list, date__created__lte=start_date)\
    .order_by('user_id', '-date').distinct('user_id')
```

If it is not, please refer to @Patrick H.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a separate model `user` right? It sounds like a `greatest-n-per-group` question, check out this answer:

[Django Query That Get Most Recent Objects From Different Categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074514/django-query-that-get-most-recent-objects-from-different-categories/2076665)